# Split date range and create record for each year in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Input

```
|EMP_KEY |START_DT    |END_DT    |
| 1      |12-1-2020   |05-06-2023|
|2       |1-1-2022    |12-21-2023|
```

OUTPUT

```
 |EMP_KEY |START_DT   |END_DT    |
 |1       |12-1-2020  |12-31-2020|
 |1       |1-1-2021   |12-31-2021|
 |1       |1-1-2022   |12-31-2022|
 |1       |1-1-2023   | 5-6-2023 |
 |2       |1-1-2022   |12-21-2022|
 |2       |1-1-2023   |12-21-2023|
```

Input and output are mentioned above. Need to split records yearly in snowflake

Comment: First row of key 2 should be `2, 1-1-2022, 12-31-2022`

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EMP_KEY, START_DT, LAST_DAY(START_DT, 'year') AS END_DT, END_DT AS MAX_DATE
    FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.EMP_KEY, DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', DATEADD(YEAR, 1, c.START_DT)), LAST_DAY(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, c.START_DT), 'year'), MAX_DATE
    FROM mytable m
     JOIN cte c ON  c.EMP_KEY = m.EMP_KEY
                    AND DATEADD(YEAR,1,c.START_DT) < m.END_DT
)
SELECT EMP_KEY, START_DT, CASE WHEN END_DT < MAX_DATE THEN END_DT ELSE MAX_DATE END AS END_DT
FROM cte
ORDER BY EMP_KEY, START_DT;
```

Results :

```
EMP_KEY START_DT        END_DT
1       2020-01-12      2020-12-31
1       2021-01-01      2021-12-31
1       2022-01-01      2022-12-31
1       2023-01-01      2023-05-06
2       2022-01-01      2022-12-31
2       2023-01-01      2023-12-21
```

The CTE performs computes the end of the first range, using `DATE_TRUNC()` and `LAST_DAY()`. Then we iteratively generate the following ranges, until the maximum date time is reached. We can then display the results with the outer query, while adjusting the end date of the last range.

Answer (score 0):

So if we use a CTE for your input data. And then build a range CTE, and then truncate the start to find the first date of the year, and then add the cross joined range values, and then add one year minus one day, to get a end of year date, then take the greatest of the start values, and the least of the end values, we will have the begin/end of each row for the data in play.

```
with data(EMP_KEY, START_DT, END_DT) as (
    select 
        $1, 
        try_to_date($2, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 
        try_to_date($3, 'MM-DD-YYYY')  
    from values
        (1, '12-01-2020', '05-06-2023'),
        (2, '01-01-2022', '12-21-2023')
), range as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null) - 1 as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>50))
)
select 
    d.*
    ,date_trunc('year', d.start_dt) as trunc_start
    ,dateadd('year', r.rn, trunc_start) as year_start
    ,dateadd('day', -1, dateadd('year', 1, year_start)) as year_end
    ,greatest(year_start, d.start_dt) as row_start
    ,least(d.end_dt, year_end) as row_end
from data as d
cross join range as r
qualify year_start <= d.end_dt
order by d.emp_key, r.rn;
```

[image]

now we can see how it's put together, we can compress that SQL somewhat:

```
with data(EMP_KEY, START_DT, END_DT) as (
    select 
        $1, 
        try_to_date($2, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 
        try_to_date($3, 'MM-DD-YYYY')  
    from values
        (1, '12-01-2020', '05-06-2023'),
        (2, '01-01-2022', '12-21-2023')
), range as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null) - 1 as rn
    from table(generator(rowcount=>50))
)
select 
    d.emp_key
    ,greatest(
        dateadd('year', r.rn, date_trunc('year', d.start_dt))
        ,d.start_dt
    ) as row_start
    ,least(
        dateadd('day', -1, dateadd('year', 1, dateadd('year', r.rn, date_trunc('year', d.start_dt))))
        ,d.end_dt
    ) as row_end
from data as d
cross join range as r
qualify dateadd('year', r.rn, date_trunc('year', d.start_dt)) <= d.end_dt
order by d.emp_key, r.rn;
```

[image]